# take in a string from input file

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to read in strings from a file, but it is only taking every other entry. Where am I going wrong with the code?

Load function:

```
void loadPhoneBookFromFile(PhoneBook& pb, ifstream& fin, const string& filename){
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string phoneNumber;

    fin.open(filename.c_str());
    while (fin >> firstName){
        getline(fin, firstName, ',');
        getline(fin, lastName, ',');
        getline(fin, phoneNumber);

        pb.addEntry(PhoneEntry(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber));
    }
}//end loadPhoneBookFromFile
```

Text file: (but no blank enter spaces between entries)

> Mary,Poppins,555.555.1111
>
> Peter,Pan,555.555.2222
>
> Mr.,Ed,555.555.3333
>
> Donald,Duck,555.555.4444
>
> Daisy,Duck,555.555.5555
>
> Houie,Duck,555.555.6666
>
> Mr.,Spock,555.555.7777
>
> Captain,Kirk,555.555.8888
>
> Snow,White,555.555.9999
>
> Sleeping,Beauty,555.555.0000

Comment: `while (fin >> firstName){



getline(fin, firstName, ',');` should seem suspicious.

Comment: Right, is there a similar "getString" type replacement for getLine() ?

Comment: My point is that it's reading `firstName` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, the '>>' operator and getline() function do not play nice together. I would change the code to this and see if it helps:

```
while (!fin.eof()){
    getline(fin, firstName, ',');
    getline(fin, lastName, ',');
    getline(fin, phoneNumber, '\n');

    pb.addEntry(PhoneEntry(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber));

}
```

Comment: That's just because of the newline left in the stream. The delimiter here is a comma, so it will read both fine in that sense. `while (!eof())` is a poor solution in any case.

Comment: Got the code  figured out: 

    void loadPhoneBookFromFile(PhoneBook& pb, ifstream& fin, const string& filename){
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string phoneNumber;
    
    
    fin.open(filename.c_str());
    while (fin >> firstName){
        
    
    
    getline(fin, firstName, ',');
    getline(fin, lastName, ',');
    getline(fin, phoneNumber, '\n');
    
    pb.addEntry(PhoneEntry(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber));
    
    }
    fin.close();
    
    }//end loadPhoneBookFromFile

Thanks to everyone for the input!

Comment: That's awesome. So you just needed to add the newline delimiter, that's weird because I thought it always considered the newline character as a delimiter even when you explicitly use one like the comma in your case.